# How to extern a global two-dimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, extern

I want to extern a global two-dimensional array:

```
float buffer[10][10];
```

I know that "extern float buffer[];" would work for an array with a single dimension, however I do not know how to extern an array with two dimensions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could just declare it as:

In a header file put:

```
extern float buffer[10][10];
```

In **one** source file put:

```
float buffer[10][10];
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, getting unresolved externals when trying to access the array.

Comment: @btcode: You put the above in header file. But you also need a declaration in compilation unit.